# numpy indexing: add vector to parts of rows, starting at varying position

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have this 2d array of zeros `z` and this 1d array of starting points  `starts`. In addition, I have an 1d array of `offsets`

```
z = z = np.zeros(35, dtype='i').reshape(5, 7)
starts = np.array([1, 5, 3, 0, 3])
offsets = np.arange(5) + 1
```

I would like to vectorize this little for loop here, but I seem to be unable to do it.

```
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    z[i, starts[i]:] += offsets[i]
```

The result in this example should look like this:

```
z
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use some [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) and [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
mask = starts[:,None] <= np.arange(z.shape[1])
z[mask] = np.repeat(offsets, mask.sum(1))
```

We could play a trick of `broadcasted multiplication` to get the final output -

```
z = offsets[:,None] * mask
```

Other way would be to assign values into `z` from `offsets` and then mask out the rest of `mask`, like so -

```
z[:] = offsets[:,None]
z[~mask] = 0
```

And other way would be have a replicated version from `offsets` as the starting `z` and then mask out -

```
z = np.repeat(offsets,z.shape[1]).reshape(z.shape[0],-1)
z[~mask] = 0
```

Of course, we would need the shape parameters before-hand.

---

If `z` is not initialized as `zeros` array, then only one of the solutions mentioned earlier would be applicable and that would need to be updated with `+=`, like so -

```
z[mask] += np.repeat(offsets, mask.sum(1))
```

Comment: thx Divakar again. Just one question. To me it looks as if already:
`z[mask] += np.repeat(offsets, mask.sum(1))` (Note the `+=`) solved my problem. So no need for the 3rd line. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DominikNeise Well I assumed `z` to be all `zeros` before going into the processing. So, if that's not the case, only the first approach would be applicable. Added a section on it.